# Как лучше осваивать язык программирования C++?

Tags: c++

Здравствуйте, хотелось бы послушать много советов о том, как лучше освоить программирование. Так как одни советуют читать книги и делать маленькие примеры, а другие советуют начать писать крупный проект и походу узнавать что нужно и как это реализовать.
Пишу на плюсах.

Comment: Начинай делать хоть что-то,а не думать.

Comment: я делаю и так, сделал не меньше 400 мелкий задачек в 100 - 400 строк, но кажется что-то упускаю.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Моё мнение такое: сначала книги и решать примеры из них. Затем писать маленькие утилиты. Затем обязательно крупный проект, иначе никогда не поймёте, зачем же нужны классы.

Кроме того, есть смысл участвовать в проектах типа Хэшкода или StackОverflow: отвечая на вопросы других можно многому научиться самому, т. к. чтобы дать хороший ответ, надо самому разобраться.

---

Возможно, C++ — не самый лучший первый язык, он избыточно сложен и не всегда логичен ради обратной совместимости. Я бы порекомендовал либо чистый C, либо Python, либо и то, и другое. Если вы *умеете* программировать и хотите лишь выучить C++, тогда, конечно, нужен именно C++.

Comment: Это скорее первый язык к которому я отнесся серьезно , сперва был паскаль, иногда C#, но С++ зацепил и не хочется уже отступать, я понимаю то, насколько он сложен, но сложность меня не пугает.

Comment: Тогда в добрый путь!

Comment: Пока читаю, я всё понимаю, иногда бывает, что прочту, подумаю что не понял, а через неделю спокойно и с радостью выполняю данную задачу без каких либо повторений.

Comment: То есть всё же можно, но сложно освоить С++ мелкими задачами и не имея хорошего опыта в других языках, я правильно понимаю?

Comment: Для мелких задач по существу не нужны ни классы, ни шаблоны, ни исключения, ни вообще какая-либо продуманная архитектура. Но на мелких задачах хорошо оттачивается «мелкая техника» — умение корректно, понятно и компактно писать код.

Comment: Под мелкими я подразумеваю такие программы как
написание своей библиотеки, тел. справочник, морской бой и т.п.

Comment: Угу, мелкие. Сколько у вас в проекте классов? Если меньше 10, проект маленький. В большом проекте классов сотни.

Answer (score 5):

Придумайте идею типа "хочу написать вот это". И начинайте писать. Поскольку пишите для себя, будет интерес. В ходе разработки таких "приложений для себя" возникает именно понимание что-где-зачем.

А вот после того как научитесь на таком примере, по прошедствии некоторого времени, если открыть код этого приложения, вы найдете много вещей которые можно улучшить-ускорить-(удалить нахрен этот ужас). Это как раз и показывает прогресс.

Пример из жизни, так сам учился с нуля.

Comment: Но перед этим вы сперва изучили синтаксис и возможности поверхностно?

Comment: @Artemiy_plus_plus, на уровне понимания что такое #include, то есть ну совсем поверхностно.

Comment: Так и есть. Если человеку его собственный код двухлетней давности не кажется плохим, он не растёт над собой.

Answer (score 2):

[image: Дерзать, делать, помогать другим]

Comment: Ну вы пессимистично как-то :-)

Comment: @VladD, первых 4 кадра весьма (и серьезно) правдивы :)

Comment: ну вот я на третьем застрял, и так понимаю что я в правильном направлении)

Comment: Если чувствуете, что застряли на мелочах, то попробуйте что-нибудь покрупнее.